# How to you check to see if file uploaded is a php file?

Tags: php

Hey i'm just wonderin how to check if the file type of upload file is php.

I have tried using:

```
$type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];

if(!$type == ".php") {

//error
} else {

//upload
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getExt($fn){
    $a=pathinfo($fn);
    return $a['extension'];
}

$type = getExt($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if($type == "php") {
//upload

} else {
//error

}
```

Comment: This worked great, very simple and easy to understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming that you want something a bit more robust than checking to see if the file extension is `.php`?  If so, then you can run the file through the PHP syntax checker (`php -l mystery_file`) via [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).

Answer (score 0):

The type var is a Mime-Type, so it doesn't describe the ending like .php, it describes the type of the data conatined, like application/x-httpd-php or text/php

Just try to upload a php file and see what

```
echo $type;
```

gives you, then you'll know what to check for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of possible php mime type

```
   text/php
   text/x-php
   application/php
   application/x-php
   application/x-httpd-php
   application/x-httpd-php-source
```

..or you can just echo the file type out and check against it.

Comment: Thanks, i'm now using this http://pastebin.com/Lgd34qZT but it always does the error even when it's another file type like an image